# How to make a CryptoCurrency (preferably using Scrypt) in depth

Tags: client, scrypt

I'm looking for a proper guide to creating a CryptoCurrency. I know this probably won't be easy, but I'm really determined, and do know how to code in some languages. (C++ Beginner).

I've heard a link say to apply a new genesis block to the code, don't even know where to start with this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the discussions at [How To Clone Scrypt Based Altcoins for Fun and Profit](http://cryptocurrencylive.com/item?id=9128)

Direct Link:
[How To Clone Scrypt Based Altcoins for Fun and Profit ?](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B82OOXRXzyeaaVVCeXByZ2JnR1U/edit?pli=1)

Comment: Thank you, read a bit and its looking good. I have actually been searching for this exact article.

Comment: Theres an error while downloading the essentials in linux. Im guessing its a general linux issue but i thought i should just say.

Comment: I've set a bounty here if you could go in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742969/hi-i-am-trying-to-make-a-cryptocurrency-altcoin-for-fun-but-i-hit-a-few-errors